# EKS using NLB ingress and multiple services deployed in node group

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

So, I am very new to using EKS with NLB ingress and managing my own worker nodes using nodegroup (ASG).
If I create a NLB ingress for the cluster and deploy multiple services inside the node group, how does NLB know that it has to load balance across service separately?
Generally, when I have not used EKS and created by own k8s cluster, I have spun one NLB per service. Not sure how would it work in case of EKS with one NLB ingress for the whole cluster with multiple service inside.
Or, do I need to create multiple NLBs somehow?
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

> when I have not used EKS and created by own k8s cluster, I have spun one NLB per service

AWS EKS is no different on this point. For a Network Load Balancer, NLB, e.g. on TCP/UDP level, you use a Kubernetes `Service` of `type: LoadBalancer`. But there are options, configured by the annotations on the `Service`. The most recent [feature is IP mode](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-aws-load-balancer-controller/). See [EKS Network Load Balancing doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html) for more configuration alternatives.

Example:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nlb-ip-svc
  annotations:
    # route traffic directly to pod IPs
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb-ip"
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

> If I create a NLB ingress for the cluster and deploy multiple services inside the node group, how does NLB know that it has to load balance across service separately?

The load balancer uses the target pods that is matched by the `selector:` in your `Service`.

The alternative is to use an Application Load Balancer, ALB that is working on the HTTP/HTTPS level using the Kubernetes `Ingress` resources. The ALB requires an Ingress controller installed in the cluster and the controller for the ALB is recently updated, see [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-aws-load-balancer-controller/)

Comment: how would the selector work if I have multiple services in the ASG? Do I need to have multiple selectors?

Comment: The ASG is managing Nodes (Virtutal Machines), but the selector is matching labels in Pods (~ containers) - the load balancer in kubernetes sends traffic to container-services. If you want the two related, you can use `NodeSelectors` or `Taints` to schedule some Pods to specific Nodes. 
ASG is autoscaling for Nodes. To get autoscaling also for Pods, you should use `HorizontalPodAutoscaler`.